# Previous ajax request changes the post URL for next form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, http-post

I am making a jQuery ajax request in a asp.net mvc page:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Go",
            data: dataObj,
            success: function (data) {
                // update html here
                }
            }
        });
```

This call is within a page, which has a form and other elements which submit to other url (lets say "/Home/Do"). Now after the ajax call returns, If I click on any other element the form still submits to url1 instead of url2

Note I tried adding a `"return false"` statement to click event handler where the ajax call is made. But even this did not help

The ajax call is made within the jQuery dialog:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({ buttons:
            [
                {
                    text: 'Next',
                    click: function () { HandleNext(); return false; }
                }
            ],
            title: 'Dialog-Title'
        });



function HandleNext() 
{

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Go",
                data: dataObj,
                success: function (data) {
                    // update html here
                    }
                }
            });

 return false;
}
```

Anybody faced a similar issue? any solutions?

Comment: Where does this `url1` variable come from? How does the view with the forms look like? Please provide more details.

Comment: url1 is set by a JavaScript function, url2 is a valid url. I do not see how this add value to my question? I could as well replace url1 with some url like "/Home/Go" and url2 with "Home/Do". Anyway let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` in the click handler is ***mandatory*** for ALL ajax requests. The web browser will visit the url otherwise. In other words: The ajax request is made first and then a regular request.

No urls can automagically be replaced with other urls. You either do it in your javascript code, or in your action/view.

Comment: Can you please point out where I should add "return false" to above code in question?

Comment: The above code is invoked by something else that you are not showing. Show that code.

Comment: Done edited the question, I have tried "return false" though as shown.